# Two Linux vms can't ping each other

Tags: linux, networking

I have a situation where there is a local network with two linux boxes and a windows box. Each of the linux boxes is running a linux vm. The windows box can ping the two linux vms. The linux vms can ping the windows box. The two linux vms cannot ping each other (not reachable). The same configuration worked with older hardware and older versions of linux but, I believe, the same version of linux on the VMs.

Anyone have any suggestions as to what I should be looking at/for?

I read that I might need to install a bridge. If so, why would the older setup not have needed a bridge?

Comment: Describe the network connections. Provide the IP addresses

Comment: I just compared the working machine with the non-working machine. The ethernet status for the working machine is "connected". The ethernet status for the non-working machine shows "connecting" and then "off". It won't connect.  But I can ping it from the windows box

Comment: I'll need to get back to on the ip addresses, but they are the same between the working and non-working systems. Supposedly, the only difference between the two systems is that the working one has newer hardware for the linux box.

Comment: Also check that your two Linux-based systems don't have the same vMAC. A MAC must be unique on the LAN

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the two VMs had the same MAC address. Thanks. Now to figure out how that happened.